# update table from multiple inputs at once

Tags: php, mysql

```
<input type='text' class='inputmode' data-id=7 value = 'sky'>
<input type='text' class='inputmode' data-id=5 value = 'earth'>
<input type='text' class='inputmode' data-id=3 value = 'sea'>
```

**js**

```
var a = $('.inputmode').eq(0).data('id');
var b = $('.inputmode').eq(0).val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'pro.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'a': a, 'b': b},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**php**

```
$sql = "update mods set mode = :mode where id = :id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ":id" => $_POST['a'],
        ":mode" => $_POST['b']
    ));
```

This works for the first `.inputmode`.
Currently I repeat this procedure for each of them.
Is there a way to solve all of them - at once ?

Comment: So get all the modes then use the [`WHERE IN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some logical issues with your code,

You have 3 Inputs, and always send one input's value to php side.

so functionally your code works fine.

and to get what you want,

1) first you need to push all of your inputs values
2) in php side iterate over those values then update your database with each value.

---

Here is a quick sample :

```
var inputmode = $('.inputmode');
var dataObj = []; // you data array
inputmode.each(function (k, v) {
    var obj = {}; // your input data object
    obj['id'] = $(this).data('id');
    obj['value'] = $(this).val();
    dataObj.push(obj); // pushing every input data object to your parent data array
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'pro.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'data': dataObj},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

while in your php side , you will receive an array under the key element 'data' -as we set in our ajax initialization- you will need to iterate over this array and execute your query as follows:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$data = $_POST['data'];

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':mode' => $value['value'],
        ':id' => $value['id']
    ));
}
```

Comment: I think you're a genius. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use Form serialize method as :

```
<form name="frmData" id="frmData" method="post">

    <input type='text' class='inputmode' name="inputmode[7]" data-id=7 value = 'sky'>
    <input type='text' class='inputmode' name="inputmode[5]" data-id=5 value = 'earth'>
    <input type='text' class='inputmode' name="inputmode[3]" data-id=3 value = 'sea'>

</form>
```

On submit you can call your ajax as below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'pro.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#frmData').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

In Php you will get array of `inputmode` use that array to update in database.

Comment: on php side I tried `echo $_POST['inputmode'];` and `echo $_POST['frmData'];` - without succes. How can I get this values in php?

Comment: You will get value using  $_POST['inputmode'][7] or $_POST['inputmode'][5]